# Purpose of Delimeters in preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I understand how to use delimiters in php's preg_match(), just not why I have to use them.

Comment: I don't think that's this is a good question, since that's how the devs of PHP decided to implement it, which is similar to perl's regex implementation to some extent. In contrast, you don't have to use delimiters for many other languages. One could as well ask why.

Comment: Since [pattern modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) can be added _after_ the pattern, there must be something by which the actual ending of the pattern can be determined …

Comment: @CBroe: it could have been done with extra parameters to the function. That's how it's done in most other languages (and generally with PHP as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delimiters are used to wrap your regular expression.  It tells the interpreter which characters make up your regular expression and which characters are relevant flags to modify how the interpreter acts on your regular expression.  Other than that, it is simply the way it was implemented.